# why gmail's phone verification code not encrypted

Tags: web-application, authentication, threat-modeling, gmail

while using google's phone verification code system, i have noticed that google phone verification code is always 6 digits

cant it be brute forced for randomly generating the 6 digits?is it there any security design implemented over there while passing through second factor?

Comment: Are you reffering to the code they send by SMS/Text or the one which you generate using an app running on your phone? Both are different algorithms.

Comment: @user93353 code whatever they sending through sms/text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Authenticator is based on the Time-based One-time Password Algorithm (TOTP).

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm

The reason that it would be difficult to brute-force is because the tokens change every 30 seconds. So after every 30 seconds of trying to brute-force, the target moves, and suddenly the token can by **any** 6 digit number again. This also means that it might change to a value you have already tried, so its possible to exhaust the entire key space without finding a valid one.

However, this in no way means that its impossible or even infeasible if no protection against brute-force is present. For example, if you were somehow able to send 1,000,000 authentication attempts in 30 secs. Even trying 1000 random numbers every 30 seconds, you might slowly get there (re: @domen's comment). However, even a simple 1 second delay on re-authentication attempts per user would render this impractical. As such, some kind of brute-force control that prevents this many authentication tries within 30 seconds is imperative.

At the very least I think Google's own login process introduces a CAPTCHA after unsuccessful attempts which would slow the process down too much and render the attack infeasible.

Comment: I don't know the details, so I might be missing something. Couldn't you just restart the process after 30 secs? Do 1000 random numbers every 30s, and you'd still have a high probability of doing it in a day. Btw. what is the name of this "probabilistic brute-force"?

Comment: I get 81% for 14 hours, 94% for one day: `1-(1-0.001)**(2*60*14) = 0.813782616726`.

Comment: @domen Yes you could. Edited to emphasise that attacks would be possible if no prevention is in place for brute-force. _Deleted previous comment as my Maths must have been wrong! Your calculation seems to be correct._ :-)

Comment: @itscooper I'm sorry but I don't get the reasoning behind your argument, when you say "even trying 1000 random numbers every 30 seconds, you might slowly get there". If the token changes to any number, every 30 seconds your chances of finding the right token reset. Perhaps 'domen' can help too.

Comment: @lorenzog the probability of getting it during the current 30 second iteration is no greater than it was during the last. However, the more times you repeat the process, the overall chances of getting it at least once increase. For example, there is a 1/6 chance of rolling a 3 on a standard die, but if you roll it 10 times you'll probably get a 3 at least once (there's a 0.838 chance that you will in fact). This is a binomial distribution.

Comment: There is usually configurable rate-limiting for failed attempts on the server side. E.g. if you fail more than 3 times within 30 seconds, all further attempts will be ignored -- so the chance of a successful random guess is 1 in 33,333.

Comment: @mricon Exactly. That's why i wanted to emphasise the need for brute-force protection in my answer.